# HT Access - Mod Rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If i use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.* controller.php
```

It would send all requests to controller.php
But if controller.php included a css file (/assets/css/main.css) then it wouldn't work, as when the browser called it, it would just redirect to controller.php

Is there a way i can fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add a [condition](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to exclude URLs that can be mapped to actually existing files:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.* controller.php
```

The `-f` keyword will test if the absolute path in `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is a path to an existing regular file in the filesystem and `!-f` is just the inverse.

But if you have a fixed list of directories you want to exclude, you could also do this:

```
RewriteCond $0 !^(assets|foo|bar)/
RewriteRule ^.* controller.php
```

This condition tests if the match of the whole `RewriteRule` pattern (referenced with `$0`) does not begin with neither `assets/` nor `foo/` nor `bar/`. If you don’t want to process the match you could also use a negated expression directly in your `RewriteRule` directive:

```
RewriteRule !^(assets|foo|bar)/ controller.php
```

Comment: This is not a very good case of security since it allows direct access to files that exist. Security by obscurity if you know what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.css$
RewriteRule ^.* controller.php
```

untested but should work.